# "this" inside mongoose virtual setter/getter gets the variable instead of the document

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

While accessing the mongoose virtual setter, "this" is the variable itself while in the documentation for virtuals([Mongoose Schemas: Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)) it references that "this" should be the main parent document as in the documentation it shows the ability to set other keys. Why is this? Has the Virtual mechanics changed or have I found a bug?
Example code:

```
const {model, Schema} = require('mongoose');

let TestSchema = new Schema({
    TestObject: {
        Test1: String
    },
    TestArray: [String]
})

TestSchema.virtual('virtual').set((Value) => {
    console.log("This in Setter", this);
}).get(() => {
    console.log("This in Getter", this);
});

let TestModel = model("TestModel", TestSchema);

let TestModelInstance = new TestModel({
    TestObject: {
        Test1: "Data"
    }, TestArray: [
        "Data2"
    ]
});

TestModelInstance.virtual = "Test";
TestModelInstance.virtual;
console.log(TestModelInstance);
```

Output:

```
This in Setter {}
This in Getter {}
{
  TestArray: [ 'Data2' ],
  _id: 5f16c03ebee17231a8b6dfc1,
  TestObject: { Test1: 'Data' }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized this was caused by using arrow-functions rather than a standard "function" keyword since arrow-functions do not have a "this" function.